# Google BigQuery: how to find the repo owner's github username for all github repos that contain a string?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm exploring the cool [github repos open dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github) on BigQuery, and hit this query I can image but can't quite write.

Curious, what BigQuery query will return:

- the github username

  - of the author

    - of each github repo

      - with a javascript file OR html file

        - that contains the string `d3`

?

Answer (score 1):

here an approximate answer, minus the constraint that the file with the match should be a javascript or html file (have a filename that ends in `.js` or `.html`)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION repoNamesHaveD3(repoNames ARRAY<STRING>)
  RETURNS INT64
  LANGUAGE js AS """
    return repoNames.some(nameHasD3) ? 1 : 0;

    function nameHasD3(name) {
      var normalized = name.toLowerCase();
      return normalized.indexOf('d3') === 0 ||
        normalized.indexOf('-d3') !== -1;
    }
  """;
SELECT author.name, repo_name
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
WHERE
  repoNamesHaveD3(repo_name) = 1
-- LIMIT 10
```

credit to [@deathmtn on twitter](https://twitter.com/deathmtn/status/899098324124487682) for this query